# 2009 Honda VTR250 motocycle losing power

Tags: honda, motorcycle, power

My 2009 Honda VTR250 is loosing power during long rides. The throttle at this time does not pick and it slowly stalls. I tried replacing the plugs but still has not worked. It only solves the problem temporarily.